# Can't execute else in conditional logic

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which is supposed to insert some data if certain conditions are met. The first 3 parts of the conditional logic work perfectly bu the else seems not to be executing if the data is a string.

In summary, if the $USSD_STRING is is an integer is(12345) the query executes perfectly. But if there is a letter at the beginning of the value i.e. (AA12345) the else seems not to be working.

I have tried this:

```
elseif (is_string("$USSD_STRING")) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO userlevel SET phone_number = '$MSISDN', ussd_string = '$USSD_STRING', user_level = '$level', session_id = '$SESSION_ID', mno_id = '$MNOID', partner_id = '$PartnerId'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

but its not working either.

```
if ( $USSD_STRING <=0) {
    }
    elseif ( $USSD_STRING ==1) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userlevel SET phone_number = '$MSISDN', ussd_string = '$USSD_STRING', user_level = '$level', session_id = '$SESSION_ID', mno_id = '$MNOID', partner_id = '$PartnerId'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
    }
    elseif ( $USSD_STRING ==2) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userlevel SET phone_number = '$MSISDN', ussd_string = '$USSD_STRING', user_level = '$level', session_id = '$SESSION_ID', mno_id = '$MNOID', partner_id = '$PartnerId'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
    }
    else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO userlevel SET phone_number = '$MSISDN', ussd_string = '$USSD_STRING', user_level = '$level', session_id = '$SESSION_ID', mno_id = '$MNOID', partner_id = '$PartnerId'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }
```

Any workarounds?

Comment: is_string($USSD_STRING) ..

Comment: Mysql_* is deprecated

Comment: what is the datatype of the `ussd_string` column in the database? And what do you mean by "not working"? Is it erroring or seems to just not do anything?

Comment: One more issue using insert query like a update query in mysql... Anyway I am not a downvoter but u plz correct them

Comment: @devpro their insert syntax is valid. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html see the 2nd example in there. and `is_string($USSD_STRING) ` will still fail them. `is_string("$USSD_STRING")` is good and being interpreted.

Comment: @fred-ii yes it will work I also used in early days. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will bet that you are declaring your variable in quotes, **something you did not post in your question.**

However, I could be wrong. But nonetheless, you have a few options for you below.

The following (and as an example)

```
$USSD_STRING = "12345";
```

or

```
$USSD_STRING = $_POST['var'];
```

Even though that is technically an integer (being set in quotes), it will still be interpreted as a string using the [`is_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php) function.

> *"Any workarounds?"*

- Yes, you have a few.

Using the following will qualify as not being a string using the `is_string()` function.

```
$USSD_STRING = 12345;
```

You would be best using `ctype_digit()` for this.

```
$USSD_STRING = "a12345"; // fail
```

The following will pass as an integer even though it is inside quotes

```
$USSD_STRING = "12345"; // pass as an integer

if (ctype_digit($USSD_STRING)) {
...
}
```

while the following will fail if a letter is introduced

```
$USSD_STRING = "a12345"; // fail. It contains a letter

if (ctype_digit($USSD_STRING)) {
...
}
```

Another option available for you to use, would be `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`.

```
if(filter_var($USSD_STRING, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT))
```

Where it will fail with

```
$USSD_STRING = "a12345";
```

but pass as (and even inside quotes):

```
$USSD_STRING = "12345";
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: I love the way of explanation my friend

Comment: @devpro Thanks. By explaining what is happening, will help shed some light on the subject ;-)